# Template that measures elapsed time of any function

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I want to create a template function that measures the elapsed time of any other function.
What I did until now:

```
using TimeDuration = std::chrono::nanoseconds;

std::tuple<FuncReturnType, TimeDuration> measureTime(Func func, Args&&... args)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ret = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    return {ret, std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeDuration>(end - start)};
}
```

It can be called  using
`auto [ret, duration] = measureTime<FuncType>(Func, args..)`
and works.

The problem is that I don't know how to make it work on functions that return `void`, because `auto ret = func(..)` does not make sense anymore. Also it would be great if I could drop the `FuncReturnType` param.

Any ideas? Thanks

P.S. I am using C++17, no boost

Comment: You might have "specialization" for `void` case. ( to return only `TimeDuration`).

Comment: `FuncReturnType` can be replaced by `decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto measureTime(Func func, Args&&... args)
{
    using FuncReturnType = decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, FuncReturnType>) {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeDuration>(end - start);
    } else {
        FuncReturnType ret = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        return std::tuple<FuncReturnType , TimeDuration>{
            ret, std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeDuration>(end - start)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `decltype` is not needed, `std::tuple` is perfectly capable of deducing the type.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: would be needed for reference type. and `decltype` is primary here for the `if constexpr`.

Comment: ah yes haven't noticed that, sorry

Comment: That looks great, thanks. Can you tell me why it needs to be "if constexpr" instead of just "if"? thanks. That's the only thing that I don't understand in your code.

Comment: `if constexpr` allows to "discard" wrong branch, so you might use different return type, and use construct which would be invalid for void return type.

Comment: @Jarod42 great, thanks, I don't want to abuse your kindness, but is there any chance that I can make it work with no-static member functions? something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/dhTebj

Comment: `std::invoke`  might help [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6TndKe).